# request as parameter of another method in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to use request as a parameter for another method. However,What should be the ? as parameter of addHeaders method?

```
def addHeaders(request:?) = {
    request.headers.get("User-Agent").getOrElse("")
}

def collectClientInfo() = Action {
   request =>
   addHeaders(request)
   ......
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/7fceab6eb7a00337bf8ed79f48274ff5a50ccf93/documentation/manual/scalaGuide/main/http/code/ScalaActionsComposition.scala#L146) sample help? I'm not sure if Play has enough documentation - if not, looking at published tests should help.

Comment: I had a look at the code. However, still couldn't figure out it. Not sure what is A in request:Request[A] mean. Seems i need to add a wrapper class

Comment: I finally figured it out with the article at http://iankent.co.uk/category/play-framework/

Comment: Cool. Yes, it's action composition. [Here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/321af079941f64cdd2cf32b407d4026f7e49dfec/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala)

Comment: In most cases, you'll want to use the `RequestHeader` object. However, your `addHeaders` method looks like it might be doing some sort of mutation, whereas Play's request object is immutable. What are you trying to do?